# Can't assign a local variable inside a stored procedure on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, local-variables

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_item`(
       IN parentId BIGINT UNSIGNED, IN jobId BIGINT UNSIGNED,
       OUT id BIGINT UNSIGNED)
    BEGIN
       DECLARE newLeft INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

       SELECT `RGT` into newLeft from `headings` where `ID`=parentId LIMIT 1;

       /* ERROR TRAP */
       IF (newLeft=0) OR (newLeft=NULL) THEN SET newLeft=1;
       END IF;
```

Problem is I can't select the result into the local variable newLeft, it always equals 1 (or 0 if I remove the error trap).  Am I missing something?  I have tried so many different approaches, even putting the "INTO newLeft" at the end of the SELECT statement.

Using MYSQL 5.4 on test machine which is Windows 7 using IIs

Comment: Are you sure there is a row in headings table that has ID parentId?  How does the call to your procedure look like?

Comment: parentId is a passed parameter and the ID is there.  SELECT works fine as it has also failed to store the result to the local variable on other SELECT statements in the stored procedure.

Comment: This must be a MYSQL bug, I have even tried:

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

MYSQL will use local variables or parameters before it uses fields in a table select inside a stored procedure  if they are the same name, and it is not case sensitive.  Notice the *where `ID`=parentId* part, it is actually asking where 0=parentId (variable id=0 at this point) as ID is a local parameter as well a field in the table, but local variables have precidence.

Changing the OUT parameter name from *id* to *outid* fixed the problem.

I suppose I could change the select to:

```
SELECT `RGT` into newLeft from `headings` where `headings`.`ID`=parentId LIMIT 1;
```

I didn't try this, I just changed the OUT parameter name.